# How to edit custom keyboard name in keyboard selection menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am creating custom keyboard app.

When tapping the globe icon to select the Emojis keyboard the option says Emojis two times with a dash between, like this: "Emojis — Emojis”. I want to need just ”Emojis”. See bellow image...

[image]
[image]

Please give me suggestion.Thanks..

Comment: Have you write anything in Keyboard extension .plist file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is First `Emojis` before - its a keyboard extension target bundle display name and second after -  its a project target bundle display name

For making change do the following steps:

- Select project -> select keyboard extension Target-> info
- Change the Bundle display name of extension target like following screenshot.

[image]

So that will be look like:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

For setting shorter name i did my project target .plist remove Bundle Display name and make there Bundle name as a **Thumb**

[image]

In my extension .plist i add Bundle Display name to **Thumb**

[image]

Now its look like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are right but i want only single name. like : "Emojis" . it is posible @Nitin Gohel

Comment: i have already done this point, working fine in 6+,5s,4s but when i run in  iPad same problem coming @Nitin Gohel thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!!!
Just write same Display name for both target.